# Run XP Application from Windows 7/8/10

Tags: windows, windows-xp, rdp, xenapp

I have a small network (windows Server 2012r2 Domain) and need to run on 10 workstations one application wich runs (well) only on Windows XP.

I was thinking of running a windows xp VM and connect to it from the workstations, wich are running windows 7-8-10.

What are the options?

Already tried

- Thinstuff XP/VS, not working on Windows 8
- Rdp RemoteAPP, cant find KB961742-v3

Comment: Window XP Mode virtual PC.  Compatibility mode checkboxes on application properties...

Comment: Does XP-Mode work on Windows 8 and 10?

Comment: Update the application.

Comment: If only this would be possible!

Answer (score -1):

You may try [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). I use it quite a lot. For server use (e.g. headless mode) see section 1.16 [in this doc](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#configbasics).

Comment: Thank you but I was looking for something simpler, like Thinstuff, it would have been perfect if it was compatible.